# Laravel: Inner join QueryException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to perform a `join` between tables in `Laravel`.
However i receive this, when loading the page:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
```

This is the query:

```
$patches = DB::table('or_patches')
    ->join('or_clients', function($join) use($authid)
    {
        $join->on('or_patches.client_id', '=', 'or_clients.id')
        >where('or_clients.customer_id'. '=', $authid);
    })
    ->get();
```

It doesn't work either, if i remove `use()`, and build the "where" upon a static value.

Detailed error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 ?' at line 1 
(SQL: select * from `or_patches` inner join `or_clients` on 
`or_patches`.`client_id` = `or_clients`.`id` and 
`or_clients`.`customer_id=` 1 )
```

Does anyone know why? I've tried using `left joins` as well, without success.

**UPDATE**: Tried changing "." to "," in the where clause. This fixed the issue. Thanks @AlexRussel.

Comment: You have a . not a comma in the authid line of your SQL :)

Comment: (Also you're missing a `-` in the `->where` but I'm guessing that's a SO transcription typo.)

Comment: Must've starred blind at this. Thanks for noticing! However, it still brings up the same error :/

Comment: The - is the formatting here, yeah :)

Comment: Are you 100% it hasn't fixed it? Is the SQL error the same? The thing that made me see it was the error: ```or_clients`.`customer_id=` 1`` - suggests you have an `=` in your field name, and then I saw it.

Comment: A-ha, new error. That looks like a completely separate thing - in fact in one of your views you don't pass an params to `->e()` (or something that calls it).

Comment: @alexrussell Your `.` to `,` answered my question perfectly. If you make it an answer, i'll mark it as best answer :)

Comment: Due to the edits on the question the answer doesn't *really* answer the question as stated, so I tried to add some context to the answer. Anyway, if you feel it's all a bit iffy feel free to just close the question entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of the SQL error (problem with the SQL `` ...`or_clients.customer_id=` 1 ``) you're getting the `=` from your query affixed to the field name. Taking a look at the code, it looks just like a simple typo where you're using `.` instead of `,` in a method call, thus concatenating the `=` to the field:

```
>where('or_clients.customer_id'. '=', $authid);
```

Should be:

```
->where('or_clients.customer_id', '=', $authid);
```